# View not changing with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

In this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/187/

The table elements are not been hidden when I hit div element "Flip!". The elements should become hidden as I'm changing the state of the structure which is determined by `ng-show`

The map is being updated but does not seem to be applied ?

I tried adding `$scope.$apply` to block when flip is invoked but same result. How to update the state of ng-show when the underlying map data structure changes ?

fiddle code :

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-show="errorMap([1])">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div ng-click="flipView()">Flip!</div>

</div>
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
     var errorMap = new Object()

     errorMap['1'] = 'true'
     errorMap['2'] = 'false';
$scope.errorMap = errorMap

    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards' }
    ];

    $scope.flipView = function(){
        alert('flipped')
        $scope.errorMap['1'] = 'false'
        $scope.$apply
    }
});
```

Update : I changed the json to contain values true , false instead of 'true , 'false'. But same result. Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/188/

Updated code  :

```
errorMap['1'] = true
 errorMap['2'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you are treating `errorMap` as a function but it is an object literal. Also you are passing an integer but the keys for the object are strings

Try

```
<td ng-show="errorMap['1']">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }}</td>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/190/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I've edited your fiddle:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
            <td ng-show="errorMap">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div ng-click="flipView()">Flip!</div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.errorMap=true;


    $scope.people = [
        { id: 1, first: 'John', last: 'Rambo' },
        { id: 2, first: 'Rocky', last: 'Balboa' },
        { id: 3, first: 'John', last: 'Kimble' },
        { id: 4, first: 'Ben', last: 'Richards' }
    ];

    $scope.flipView = function(){
        alert('flipped');
        $scope.errorMap = !$scope.errorMap; //this is actual flipping (show/hide)

    }
});
```

Waiting for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

It was just a little syntax erro. You have `( )`  in `errorMap([1])`. Without this one, all is fine.

```
<td ng-show="errorMap[1]">{{ person.first + ' ' + person.last }} </td>
```

Moreover, I think a simple boolean could do the trick.

There is the forked [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krqnesuz/)